# How to swap a node in a doubly linked list with its previous one

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have a project and one of the things I have to do is swap a node given as a parameter to a method with the one before it. If it's the first one, it's fine as is, but my roommate and I have been trying this all day. We tried making multiple temp nodes and messing with them and tried swapping just the elements of the nodes. It's hard to tell exactly what we're doing wrong. I feel like this should have been a lot simpler than we make it out to be, but we've spent a lot of time doing this. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've made a little "before" and "after" diagram, right? That'll help get this clear in your head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Before:**

```
pp -> p -> node -> n
```

**After:**

```
pp -> node -> p -> n
```

**So you need to update:**

1. `pp.next`
2. `node.previous`
3. `node.next`
4. `p.previous`
5. `p.next`
6. `n.previous`

**Therefore:**

```
private void swapWithPrevious(Node node) {
   if(n.previous == null) { // first node
       return;
   }

   Node p = node.previous;
   Node pp = p.previous;
   Node n = node.next;
   if(pp != null) {
       pp.next = node;
   }
   node.previous = pp;
   node.next = p;
   p.previous = node;
   p.next = n;
   if(n != null) {
       n.previous = p;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a class problem.

Each node has a pointer to the previous and a pointer to the next node, right? The head has no "previous" pointer (e.g. it's null or has some special value).

To swap a node, you start with:

```
Node node = the node passed in
Node previousNode = node.previous
```

Excepting the special case where previousNode is null:

```
previousNode.next = node.next;         // this used to point to node
previousNode.previous.next = node;     // this used to point to previousNode
node.previous = previousNode.previous; // this used to point to previousNode
node.next.previous = previousNode;     // this used to point to node
node.next = previousNode;
previousNode.previous = node;
```

Comment: You forgot to update ``previousNode.previous.next`` and ``node.next.previous``

Comment: Jean's right, guys--I'll update the answer in a moment.